# JDBC pooling Oracle driver Socket read timed out

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling

I run Java EE application on Glassfish server v3 together with Oracle 12 DB on the same machine under Windows Server 2012 64bit. I use latest ojdbc7 driver.

Connection pool config:

```
<jdbc-connection-pool validation-table-name="DUAL" steady-pool-size="20" statement-cache-size="100" associate-with-thread="true" statement-timeout-in-seconds="30" idle-timeout-in-seconds="60" max-wait-time-in-millis="2000" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="20" datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" pool-resize-quantity="5" max-pool-size="60" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="dbPool" is-connection-validation-required="true">
  <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"></property>
  <property name="user" value="xxx"></property>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))"></property>
  <property name="password" value="xxx"></property>
  <property name="portNumber" value="1521"></property>
  <property name="databaseName" value="orcl"></property>
  <property name="serverName" value="127.0.0.1"></property>
  <property name="oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout" value="300000"></property>
  <property name="oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT" value="10000"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

After 2 or 3 hours, when there is more than 1 user (3-5) using my application, it stops responding and I get this in glassfish logs

```
javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator|_ThreadID=152;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool dbPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: IO Error: Socket read timed out
[...]
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: IO Error: Socket read timed out
```

From the database side it looks like this

```
Fatal NI connect error 12560, connecting to:
 (LOCAL=NO)

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 13-JUN-2014 03:14:49
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12560

TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (3404) as a result of ORA-609
```

When I just reset db listener everything works ok for next 1-2 hours (depends on application load). So temporary solution is to run bat script from windows scheduler to reset the listener every 1h.

I tried everything I could find - applied these parameters:

```
- Sqlnet.ora:
SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=180
SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=5
- Listener.ora:
INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER_IPC=120
```

But still without success

Comment: I would say you have Oracle server crashes. Most likely out of native memory or handles. Client connections are typically not this unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Since the client is at the same server as the database you could try the IPC protocol instead of TCP as a workaround.
It is not only independent of the TCP traffic conditions but also MUCH quicker than TCP.

Your connection string would be something like

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY = LISTENER)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))
```

As you are using connection pooling, your only verification should be dead connection (SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME).
Oracle has several notes explaining it's functionality but it basically says it's deppendent of the TCP network layout:

- Dead Connection Detection (DCD) Explained - Doc ID 151972.1.
- Common Questions About Dead Connection Detection (DCD) - Doc ID 1018160.6

It could be a profile configuration problem (the user connected is not allowed to stay inactive for more than x seconds, the IDLE_TIME limit). 
You could verify your profiles with:

```
set linesize 1000
set pagesize 1000
select *
from dba_profiles
order by profile;
```

Also get your network checked.

Comment: IDLE_TIME in dba_profiles is UNLIMITED. Will try IPC protocol. Does thin driver support it? Does any of timeout parameters I've set apply to it?

Comment: INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT is for avoiding Denial of Service attacks. A client estabilishes a connection but provides no authentication. This aims to set a limit for this process, killing connections who don't seem to do anything. Did you try the IPC protocol?

Comment: To use IPC I have to switch to OCI driver, I'm working on it

Comment: When I use OCI driver with IPC, my JVM crashes with stackoverflow....